# Accessibility Service - send keyboard events

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to send Keyboard events using Accessibility Service, but im failing.  A scenario is once user starts Accessibility Service, the service would run a handler which outputs "20" every 20 seconds. If the person opens let's say, chrome and taps on the address bar, they will start to see 20202020... Can this be done with an Accessibility Service?

This is what i tried

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
import android.widget.Toast

class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    companion object {
        const val TAG ="MyAccessibilityService"
    }

    private val handler = Handler()

    private val runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            // Send the 'A' key event
            val keyEvent = KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)
//            dispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent)

            // Schedule the next execution
            handler.postDelayed(this, 20 * 1000)
        }
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {}

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: Running")

        if (event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) {
            val accessibilityNodeInfo = rootInActiveWindow
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "A")
            accessibilityNodeInfo?.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, bundle)
        }
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent Connected: Running")
        val info = AccessibilityServiceInfo()
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC
        info.notificationTimeout = 100
        serviceInfo = info

        // Start sending 'A' key event every 20 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20 * 1000)
        super.onServiceConnected()
    }

    override fun onKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent KEY: Running")

        return super.onKeyEvent(event)
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        // Remove the callback when the activity is destroyed
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }

    private fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).